# Under the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$, how come $\Bbb{Q}$ isn't a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

By definition, a set $A\subset S$ is closed iff $S\backslash A$ is open. Now, the open sets on the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$ take the form $\bigcup_i(a_i, b_i)$ for some real numbers $a_i$ & $b_i$. Then it is easy to see that closed sets take the form $\Bbb{R}\backslash \bigcup_i(a_i, b_i) = \bigcup_i[c_i, d_i]$ for some real numbers $c_i$ and $d_i$. This further means that a set that is the countable union of singleton sets (i.e. $\bigcup_i \{r_i\}$) is closed. Therefore, for example, $\Bbb{Z}$ is closed.

Now, if everything I've said up to this point is correct, what's confusing me is how $\Bbb{Q}$ isn't a closed. The reason I assume it's not a closed set is because I was told that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, which means that $\text{cl}(\Bbb{Q}) = \Bbb{R}$, so if $\Bbb{Q}$ was closed then $\text{cl}(\Bbb{Q})=\Bbb{Q}\ne \Bbb{R}$. We can write $\Bbb{Q} = \bigcup_{\substack{p,\ q\in\Bbb{Z} \\ (p,\ q)=1}}\left\{\frac p q\right\}$, which is the union of a countable number of singleton sets. By what I said above, this should be closed, but clearly it isn't, so what gives? I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense, but I can't exactly draw the connection. That, or something I said above is incorrect.

Can anyone give me some pointers? What's wrong in my thought process?

Comment: why do you think a countable union of singletons is closed?

Comment: $\bigcup_i[c_i, d_i]$ is closed for all $c_i, d_i\in\Bbb{R}$ with $c_i \le d_i$ right? Then just set $c_i = d_i$ and you get singleton sets.

Comment: The axioms of topology states that *The union of any **finite** number of closed sets is also closed.*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\Bbb{R}\backslash \bigcup_i(a_i, b_i) = \bigcup_i[c_i, d_i]$? For instance, $\Bbb{R}\setminus (a,b) = (-\infty,a]\cup [b,\infty)$.

Comment: @user3002473 No, the arbitrary union of closed sets needn't be closed. Take for example the union of $[0,1-1/n]$.

Comment: The union of (an arbitrary number of) open sets is open. As has been mentioned by someone else, the _finite_ union of closed sets is closed.

Comment: @HowDoIMath I guess I just assumed that for any countable union of open intervals it's complement in $\Bbb{R}$ is the union of closed sets.

Comment: @ClementC. I guess I just never learned that, or never drew that conclusion from the axioms of closed sets I learned. Why then is it only the union of *finite* closed sets that is closed, but the union of *countable* open sets is open?

Comment: The intersection of finitely many open sets is open, and the (arbitrary) union of open sets is open. Taking the complement, the union of finitely many closed sets is closed, and the (arbitrary) intersection of closed sets is closed. (Note that arbitrary in the above means... arbitrary. Not necessarily even countable.)

Comment: A countable union of *isolated* singletons is closed. For on open set S = $\cup$ (a_i, b_i) it follows that R/S = $\cup$ [c,d] but it does *NOT* follow that for any K =$\cup$[c,d] there is an open R/S = $\cup$[c,d] (or in other words, it doesn't follow $\cup$[c,d]$ is open.)  Each [c,d] need not be separated from the "next" [e,f] via an open (d, e).  As (d,e), in turn, may contain infinitely many "hole" points of K. Consider $\cup${irrational}. It's compliment, Q, does not contain *any* (a,b) at all.  Because the irrationals are not isolated.

Comment: @fleablood You may want to consider reformatting your comment, it's causing the page to render strangely on certain devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little mistake of the OP: 
$\Bbb{R}\backslash \bigcup_i(a_i, b_i) = \bigcup_i[c_i, d_i]$.

Not true. According to De Morgan's Law
$$
\Bbb{R}\backslash \bigcup_i(a_i, b_i)=\bigcap_i\big(\mathbb R\backslash (a_i, b_i)\big)=\bigcap_i\big(\mathbb R\backslash (-\infty,a_i]\cup [b_i,\infty)\big).
$$

Comment: This is the mistake I was making. My misunderstanding stems from the fact that the topology axioms I have in my notes say "the union of any number of open sets is open" and "the intersection of any number of open sets is open". Thanks!

Comment: It should be that the intersection of any finite number of open sets is open.  What you have said is not true.  Take the intersection of $(-\frac 1n,\frac 1n), n \in \Bbb N$, which is $\{0\}$ as a counterexample.

Comment: That's not incompatible with the OPs statement.  Which is true if we abuse notation and assume {x} = [x,x] and (-$\infty$, x] = [-$\infty$, x].

Answer (score 0):

The closure of a subset of a topological space $A\subset X$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ containing $A$. The closure of a closed set is the set itself. Sounds logical. Now $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ so the closure of $\Bbb{Q}$ is $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ is therefore not closed in $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The union of *isolated* singletons is closed.  To wit:

You state the if $S = \bigcup_i(a_i, b_i)$ is open then

$\Bbb{R}\backslash \bigcup_i(a_i, b_i) = \bigcup_i[c_i, d_i]$

This is true if we take liberty with notation and allow {$x$} to be written as [$x,x$] and allow ($-\infty, x$] to be written as [$-\infty, x$].

But it doesn't follow that if $K = \bigcup_i[a_i, b_i]$ is closed then $\Bbb{R}\backslash \bigcup_i[a_i, b_i] = \bigcup_i(c_i, d_i)$ for some $c_i, d_i$.

Assume $[a_i, b_i] \subset K$ with $b_i$ beings such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $(b_i, b_i + \epsilon)$ there exists a $y_{\epsilon}$ such that $y_{\epsilon} \in (b_i, b_i + \epsilon)$ but it doesn't follow that $(b_i, y_{\epsilon}) \subset K^c$ and it is quite possible there is absolutely no $\delta > 0$ such that $(b_i, b_i + \delta) \subset K^c$.

So your conclusion that a countable union of singletons is closed is incorrect.  It *is* correct that a countable union of *isolated* singletons is closed but if the are not isolated the union is not necessarily closed.  (Isolated means that there *does* exist a $\delta > 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x)$ and $(x, x + \delta)$ are not in K.)

In particular if $K =\bigcup_{\alpha}[x_{\alpha}; \text { not rational}]$, then no $(x_{\alpha}, x_{\alpha} + \epsilon) \subset K^c = \mathbb Q$ exist.  ($\mathbb Q$ is not open.)